# Creating a Session to not to vote again in poll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, vote

I've created simple using jQuery AJAX and JSON. I want to know how to create a Session so that the user will not be able to vote again. Following is my code.

I am new to Sessions and jQuery. Please tell me how to complete my task.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#poll").click(function(){

                var count = '';

                if (document.getElementById("vote1").checked) {
                        count = 0;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("vote2").checked) {
                        count = 1;
                }

                var jsonV= 
                {
                    "vote": count
                };

     $.ajax({
        type  : "POST",
        url   : "poll_vote.php",
        data  : jsonV,
        dataType: "json",
        success : function (responseText){

          console.log("Shit is working "+responseText);
           $("#result").html(responseText.vote);

        },
        complete : function(){
            $("#poll").slideUp();
        },
        error : function(error,responseText){
          // alert("Server not Responding. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Please Try again Later");
          console.log(error);
          $("#result").html(error+ responseText);
          alert(count);
        }
      });
    });

});

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];


$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);
// $decode = json_decode($encode);
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$male = $array[0];
$female = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $male = $male + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $female = $female + 1;
}

$insertvote = $male."||".$female;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);

$table =  (
"<h2>Results:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Male :</td>
<td>
<img src='poll.gif'
width= ".(100*round($male/($female+$male),2)).
"height='20'>".
(100*round($male/($female+$male),2))." %"  .
"
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> Female :</td>
 <td>
 <img src='poll.gif'
 width=". (100*round($female/($female+$male),2)) .
"
 height='20'>".
 (100*round($female/($female+$male),2))." %" ."

 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>");
$list  = array('vote' => $table);
    $encode = json_encode($list);
 echo $encode;
 ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id= "poll">
<h3> What is your Gender? </h3>
<form>
Male : 
<input type = "radio" name = "vote"  id="vote1" >
<br>
Female :
<input type = "radio" name = "vote"  id="vote2" >
</form>
</div>
<p><div id= "result"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Cookies would be a better option I guess.

Comment: use `session_start()` function.and set session variables.as `$_SESSION["login"] = "green";`

Comment: @LShetty Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your PHP code start a session and then check if there is required session value, for example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['voted']){
    $list  = array('vote' => 'You have already voted!');
    $encode = json_encode($list);
    echo $encode;
    exit;
    //or, shorter: die(json_encode(array('vote' => 'You have already voted!')));

}
$_SESSION['voted'] = 1;
//rest of your code here
```

Comment: did it. Can you tell me how to do this in cookies?

Comment: same way, just replace $_SESSION with $_COOKIE.